# Get results of the model only if child with Foreign key has records

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models as follows:

```
class Tutorial(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=tutorial_image_path)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)

class Video(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    tutorial = models.ForeignKey(Tutorial, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, null=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, null=False)
    iframe = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_on']

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I want to get all `Tutorials` where there is at least one video in `Video` model

Something as follows:

```
results = Tutorial.objects.filter(id__in=Video.objects.filter....)
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#isnull)

```py
results = Tutorial.objects.filter(video__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Maybe (because I didn't test this) you could also do:

```py
results = Tutorial.objects.select_related("video").filter(video__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Comment: That gives me error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'video_set' into field`

Comment: I've edited my answer. Can you check now?! Most likely you got a list of fields along with that `Cannot resolve keyword...` error.

Comment: It should be just `video__isnull`: If you don't set a `related_name` on the fk field, then it uses the lowercase name of the model for lookups. Also you might want to add `distinct()` because it will duplicate the `Tutorial` objects that have multiple videos.

Comment: Now I get `*** django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'video'. Choices are: author` . I've added full models in the question.